# How to get list of all object files?

Tags: qt, qmake

I generated an empty project with Qt Creator. There is `.pro`-file:

```
QT       += core gui
QT += widgets
TARGET = untitled2
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h
FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui
write_file("objects", OBJECTS)
```

According [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#objects), OBJECTS variable is automatically populated from the SOURCES variable. But actually this variable is empty.

How to get list of all object files, including `moc`s? For this `.pro`-file list must be like this:

```
debug/main.o
debug/mainwindow.o
debug/moc_mainwindow.o
```

Qmake (3.1) (Qt 5.15.2)

Answer (score 0):

Once you build QT source in Release / Debug mode then you can check generated Directory on Parent Folder of your Source Code.
In that you can see release and debug folders formed, where you will get list of all object files for **SOURCES** variable.

Comment: Good way, but is it possible to get objects list BEFORE the sources will be built? MAKEFILE contains this list, so qmake have to produce it.

Comment: @maestro:  You mean class objects or Object files for source files ?

Comment: object files (`*.o`).

Comment: @maestro: Object files are generated usually after you build your source.

Comment: @maestro: Usually gcc have option flag as -E or -c where we can decide upto what step we want to compile our code. But I did not find such flag for qmake.

Comment: Object files are generated after you build your source, but the list od object files is known before build: Makefile contains this list.